# RestSharp How to deal with different JSON response formats for same query

Tags: c#, json, wpf, rest, restsharp

I've been fighting with this for a while and I think is time to ask for some help.

I'm using **RestSharp** to connect to my local **PHP REST API**. The format I'm returning the api results is as follows (JSON):

```
{
"estado": "login_correcto",
"content": {
   "id": 1,
   "nombreusuario": "daniaguado",
   "contrasena": "qwerty",
   "email": "daniel@zadecon.com",
   "nivelacceso": 5,
    "created_at": "2017-08-01 10:31:16",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    }
}
```

For this, I've created a custom `Usuario` class (User) and a custom `ResponseUsuario` as follows:

```
class Usuario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombreusuario { get; set; }
    public string contrasena { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int nivelacceso { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

Then the ResponseUsuario:

```
class ResponseUsuario
{
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public Usuario content { get; set; }
}
```

The response is being parsed ok when the response is ok (202) and the user exists.

But, when the login is incorrect, in "content" I'm returning a message, not an User:

```
{
 "estado": "login_incorrecto",
 "content": "La contraseña es incorrecta / Password incorrect"
}
```

So, If I use `ResponseUsuario` there, queryResult.Data is null, because it cannot map the content to the `Usuario` class. The fact is that if I don't use ResponseUsuario and instead use a `Response` class, in which content variable is type object, I cannot cast it to `Usuario` and I cannot deal with it.

This is the more general `Response` class which I understand I should be using for all my queries:

```
class Response
{
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public object content { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, this is my RestSharp query:

```
ApiClient api = new ApiClient(); // Just create the client with some common parameters

var request = new RestRequest("usuarios/login", RestSharp.Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("nombreusuario", textbox_usuario.Text);
request.AddParameter("contrasena", textbox_contrasena.Text);

var queryResult = api.cliente.Execute<ResponseUsuario>(request);

if (queryResult.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Usuario u = (Usuario) queryResult.Data.content; // Gives error when using Execute<Response> (object content)
    String s = queryResult.Data.estado;

    Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"OK - {u.nombreusuario} - {u.email} - Acceso: {u.nivelacceso}");
} 
else
{
    Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Query Failed: {queryResult.StatusDescription}, estado: {queryResult.Data.estado}"); // Giving error when using Execute<ResponseUsuario>
}
```

How can I fix the cast to Usuario (or the matching class for content)? I think the `Response` class should be common to all my queries to the API and then cast the Content part to it's appropiate class, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by generating a custom Reflection from the Dictionary Object to the class, that is, at the end, a custom parser.

I created a new class `Tools` and added a conversion function:

```
public static T CastToObject<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dict) where T : class
{
   Type type = typeof(T);
   T result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   foreach (var item in dict)
   {
       type.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(result, item.Value, null);
   }
   return result;
 }
```

And on the Api Query, added a switch-case depending on the Status code:

```
var queryResult = api.cliente.Execute<Response>(request);

switch(queryResult.StatusCode)
{
    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
        Usuario u = Tools.CastToObject<Usuario>((IDictionary<string, object>)queryResult.Data.content);
        String status = queryResult.Data.estado;
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"OK - {u.nombreusuario} - {u.email} - Acceso: {u.nivelacceso}");
        break;
    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Login Failed: User does not exists");
            break;
    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Login Failed: Incorrect Password");
            break;
    default:
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Error when connecting to the API");
            break;
}
```

Further I'll need to deal with responses containing list inside the `content` field but I think the procedure will be something similar to this one: to create a custom parser for the `content` field and cast it to my class.

Answer (score 2):

Really late to the party. I have met a similar problem when an API returned different structures on error vs. 200. I gave up RestSharp's typed call and explicitly deserialize the payload.

```
var response = RestClient.Execute<IdamValidationResultApiModel>(request);
if (response.IsSuccessful)
   var t1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirstType>(response.Content);
else
   var t2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecondType>(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

check if (queryResult.Data.content is Usuario) and cast only if it is true

else cast to string.

Comment: That's not working for me. I know when it is a Usuario, because it is returning 202 status.

The thing is, when using `Execute<Response>` (where, remember, content is type object), the queryResult.Data.content is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` and cannot be casted to 
`Usuario`, even when I know it's a `Usuario`.

Comment: If the response contains the values in a dictionary, which means you can cast directly, why don't you write a parser from the dictionary object to your user object?

Comment: Then I'll need to make a Parser for every response I receive? I was planning of having different objects for every response content. I'll need to make a parser for every query?

Answer (score 0):

Does each response return a different Http status code? I'm guessing that you're returning a 401 from your rest api. If this is the case:

You can then use a switch to deal with other status codes.

```
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = queryResult.StatusCode;
    int numericStatusCode = (int)statusCode;

    switch (numericStatusCode)
    {
        case 202:
            dynamic content = queryResult.Data.content;
            Usuario u = content.content; 
            String s = queryResult.Data.estado;
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"OK - {u.nombreusuario} - {u.email} - Acceso: {u.nivelacceso}");
            break;
        case 401:
            //Deal with the failed login
            break;
    }
```

Finally, the reason that you're getting an error, is because you're trying to cast the response object which is of type UsarioResponse to Usario. You need to navigate the json to find content.content (as seen above)

Comment: That's not working. I'm actually making the separation by statusCode. `queryResult.Data.content` is actually the content, not `content.content`. It could be named potato, it would be `queryResult.Data.potato`. The problem is not there. The problem still occurs, cannot cast from Dictionary to Usuario. I'll need to make a custom parser finally.